# How can I push the data contained in `top`--in a Macintosh terminal session--to a file called `file.txt`?

Tags: macos, unix, fileoutputstream

How can I push the data contained in `top`--in a Macintosh terminal session--to a file called `file.txt`?

Comment: This question probably makes more sense on the http://superuser.com/ site, as it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, to capture the output of the `top` command to a file called `file.txt`, use the syntax below:

```
top -l 1 > file.txt
```

(Updated to reflect different syntax of OSX `top` command.  See http://ss64.com/osx/top.html for all options.)

Comment: Nor does `top -n > file.txt`.